# Did the gender of "der Ozean" change?

Tags: gender, history

I was looking through [some old maps](http://idb.ub.uni-tuebingen.de/opendigi/FhVIII16_fol#p=6) published in Hamburg in the 1790s and the label *Atlantische Ocean* stuck out to me.

[image]

I would expect it to show *Atlantischer Ozean* (and looking at modern maps seems to confirm this), because *der Ozean* is a masculine noun. I know that German spelling has changed over time, but has the gender of this word also changed? Or is there a reason why one might use *Atlantische Ozean* without a preceding *der*?

Comment: Kannst Du ähnlich alte Karten der arabischen Halbinsel finden, und überprüfen, ob dort "Rotes Meer" oder "Rote Meer" steht - ersatzweise, natürlich weiter nördlich, das Schwarze Meer?

Comment: On the map for Massachusetts it says *Atlantisch**er** Ozean* (and also *klein**er** See*). On the other hand, other maps have *die unterstrichen**e** Namen*. Some insecurity with regard to strong/weak adjective endings?

Comment: It says  *Atlantischer Ocean*, to be precise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My best guess is, the *Der* can be found below the *Ipswich* peninsula, the same way as the trailing *an* of *Ocean* in the upper part of the excerpt.

As you can check on [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Ozean), in the *Etymologie section*:

- no other gender than masculine is mentioned
- Latin *oceanus* and Greek *Ὠκεανός* were also masculine

So I doubt any intermittent deviations. [Brockhaus 1894](https://www.retrobibliothek.de/retrobib/seite.html?id=5180029&imageview=true) also has it as masculine on the map, the examples from [Grimm](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/ocean) by Goethe (written as *Göthe* there) and Schiller confirm this as does [Adelung](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/Adelung?lemid=O00228), the dictionary from 1793.

Comment: Hey I appreciate the answer. The clipping doesn't show it, but that's the bottom of the map. The same spelling is used on all but one of the maps in the collection including those with plenty of space.

Comment: The DWDS link is very helpful. I'll just leave the question open for a bit longer in case anyone comes up with an explanation. It seems like an odd mistake to make repeatedly.

Comment: Maybe I’m way off the mark, but is it possible that the “der” is implied and left off because they wanted to save space on the map? “Der atlantische Ozean” would be correct...

Comment: @eurieka I have seen exactly the same from some older generation teachers of mine when they were writing on the blackboard. Could be the same reasoning.